# How to install Oyente on Windows 10?

Tags: contract-development

Can some body please guide me how to install Oyente on Windows 10? I have found Oyente for Linux but not for windows on github. Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know [how to use docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) & have it [installed on Windows 10](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

There are instructions on how to use it via a Docker container in the "Quick Start section".

See the README file via the official GitHub repo  [here](https://github.com/melonproject/oyente)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right now I can't install Docker because I have windows 10 home. Is there any other way o get Oyente?

Comment: Yes. That's true. Probably cause the new Docker has uses Hyper-V, a feature absent in Home edition.

Luckily, there is the old version of docker that doesn't use Hyper-V &  should work on Windows10 Home https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/

Your other options, however, are a) Install a VM with virtual box, b) Dual boot alongside windows.


Native Oyente support for Mac & Windows is still pending unfortunately